# How to store the out put of find command to a array in csh scripting

Tags: shell, scripting, csh

I want to store each output of find command at each index of a array .

I am using

set arr = `find $path -name "*.txt"`
  echo $arr

actual output:
  file1.txt file.txt file3.txt

expected output:
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt

Answer (score 0):

Use parenthesis `()` to assign an array and use backtick to execute the `find` command :

```
set arr = (`find $path -name "*.txt"`)
```

and to see the array elements

```
echo ${arr[*]}
```